# How much data can I hold in Graphview Android

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have created a graph in Android Studio using Graphview and it simply appends data to the graphview every 300ms. I was wondering how much data can I keep appending to the series until it crashes the whole app?

I saw that an arraylist can hold up to 2 billion elements so would that be the same for graphview?

I also wanted to try to clear the data if it reached that high by doing the follow (I tested for 30 data points):

```
series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastX++, new_y), true, 30);
if (lastX == 30){
    lastX = 0;
    series.resetData(new DataPoint[] {});
}
```

However, the above just crashed my app when x = 30.